# Optimize Php function that is too slow

Tags: php, function

i made this function to test if the content has 301 redirections..
Please can you help me opimize it better because it's too slow

```
function contains_http_301_link($content, $current_site){
    $pattern = '~<a(.*?)href="([^"]+)"(.*?)>~';
    $links = array();
    // Check if there is a url in the content
    if(preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $urls)) {
        foreach($urls[0] as $url){
            // get external links

            if ( !strpos( $url, $current_site )) {                                   // Is an external link
                $vowels = array('"' ,"<a", " ", "href", "=", ">");
                $links[] = str_replace($vowels, "", $url);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $_headers = @get_headers($link,1); 
        if($_headers && strpos( $_headers[0], '301')) { 
            return true;
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: _Trivial change_ You always load the same content into this `$vowels = array('"' ,"<a", " ", "href", "=", ">");` so do it outside the loop

Comment: Might be easier to help if we know more about the input to the function

Comment: It takes the post content as input @RiggsFolly

Comment: If the `links` array contains many duplicates, you can remove these duplicates before fetching headers (which should be the most time consuming function here). Use `array_unique()` before your get_header-loop

Comment: @Gowire I tried it and i got this error 
Warning: array_unique() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in /var/www/html/script/export_csv/Script_301_Said.php on line 97

Comment: after you found all links in your input, you start retrieving all these pages from all these sites. If such link is an page containing 10MB of data, you will get this 10MB data (and so for each link). But you  are only interested in the headers. So use strom_context_set_default and ask only for the HEAD. See https://www.php.net/get_headers Example #2

Comment: *"Please can you help me opimize it better because it's too slow"* if you're looking for code review then you should have posted your question at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). You'll probably find more people engaging there.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the last for-loop to:

```
 <?php
 stream_context_set_default(
 array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'HEAD'
      )
  ))
);
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $_headers = get_headers($link,1); 
    if($_headers && strpos( $_headers[0], '301')) { 
        return true;
    } 
}
?>
```

or as

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
'http' => array(
    'method' => 'HEAD'
   )
 );
foreach ($links as $link) {
$_headers = get_headers($link,1, $context); 
if($_headers && strpos( $_headers[0], '301')) { 
    return true;
}
```

}

By the way: if the first of 10 links found will return 301, your function returns TRUE. The same if it is the last. So your function just checks if at least one has a redirect 301 (and not 302 or 303)